# Why can't PIL load my image? Error: not enough image data

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, grpc

I am trying to take a Python `bytes object` and read it in using PIL like this `image = Image.frombytes(mode="RGB", size=(w, h), data=image)`. This gives me the following error `not enough image data`.

I've tried different image formats and different modes with no luck. I'm opening the image on a client, sending it in a gRPC request, and then converting it to a PIL object because the library I am using requires the image to be a PIL object. Here are the code snippets:

```
image = cv2.imread(<PATH>)
w, h, c = image.shape
is_success, image_buf_arr = cv2.imencode(".png", image)
byte_image = image_buf_arr.tobytes()
```

Then I send the image data as a byte array to the server which does:

```
image = Image.frombytes(mode="RGB", size=(w, h), data=image)
```

Any ideas of what to try or what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
image = io.BytesIO(image)
image = Image.open(image)
```

And it now works.